# Evaluation of double integral.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $\iint_R \sqrt{|y-x^2|}d xd y $
>
> where $R = [-1, 1; 0,2]$

I am stuck at starting phase. Can't think of any substitution.

Comment: To get rid of the absolute value sign, split it into two integrals, both for $x\in [-1,1]$, depending on whether $y\ge x^2$ or $y<x^2$.

Comment: How to define the range? I am not aware about the notion used here

Comment: I assumed that the (odd) notation $[-1,1;0,2]$ means $[-1,1]\times [0,2]$. If it means something else, then adjust my comment above accordingly.

Comment: Then I am stuck with  $\int{|2-x^2|}^{3/2} d x $ over x goes to -1 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the limits of x do not depend on the limits for y, we can interchange them freely

$\int_0^2 \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt {|y - x^2|} \;dx \;dy = \int_{-1}^1\int_0^2  \sqrt {|y - x^2|} \;dy \;dx$

The curve $y = x^2$ defines whether $|y-x^2| = y - x^2$ or $x^2 - y$

$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{x^2} \sqrt {x^2 - y} \;dy\; dx + \int_{-1}^1\int_{x^2}^2 \sqrt {y - x^2} \;dy \;dx$

$\int_{-1}^1 - (x^2 - y)^\frac32|_0^{x^2} \; dx + \int_{-1}^1 (y - x^2)^{\frac32} |_{x^2}^2 \;dx$

$\int_{-1}^1 x^3 \; dx + \int_{-1}^1 (2 - x^2)^{\frac32}\;dx$

If you are still stuck...try, $x = \sqrt 2 \sin t$